# java.util.logging: where does handler output go when running from Windows comand prompt?

Tags: java, command-prompt, java.util.logging

Just getting to grips with this logging module.

When I run it in Eclipse the console output goes where I expect: console handler to console, file handler to file.

When I run from the command prompt I have no idea where the console output or the file output is going.

This is how I configure it:

```
    Handler consoleHandler = null;
    Handler fileHandler = null;
    try {
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

        // Creating consoleHandler and fileHandler
        consoleHandler = new DualConsoleHandler();

        // 1000 bytes max, 5 files max, append mode = true
        fileHandler = new FileHandler("./output/logging/log%g.xml", 10000, 5, true);

        // Assigning handlers to logger object
        logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler);

        // Setting levels to handlers and logger
        consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);

        logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error occur in FileHandler.", exception);
    }
```

The `DualConsoleHandler` looks like this (found in another SO question), the idea being to print INFO or lower to stdout, but WARNING or higher to stderr:

```
public class DualConsoleHandler extends StreamHandler {

    private final ConsoleHandler stderrHandler = new ConsoleHandler();

    public DualConsoleHandler() {
        super(System.out, new SimpleFormatter());
    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        if (record.getLevel().intValue() <= Level.INFO.intValue()) {
            super.publish(record);
            super.flush();
        } else {
            stderrHandler.publish(record);
            stderrHandler.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your DualConsoleHandler code is going to close the standard out. Override `close` and the implementation should call `this.flush(); stderrHandler.close();`

Answer (score 1):

> When I run from the command prompt I have no idea where the console output or the file output is going.

The console output goes to the console.

The file output goes to the path you gave it. i.e. `./output/logging/log%g.xml`

Look in the directory under where you ran it for a `output/logging` directory.

Comment: Thanks, but neither output is going to those locations: the console (command prompt) just shows the command to run the app, i.e. "java -cp xxxx App"... with nothing under it.  And there is no file writing activity under output\logging\ in the directory where it's being run.  Honestly, I'd really have to be even more dull-witted than I am to put up this question if the answer were this simple...

Comment: @mikerodent in that case, your expectation of what it should do is correct, perhaps the question should be; why is it not writing to the console or file as expected.

Comment: @mikerodent I would try a much simpler example, e.g. does System.out.println work? does a much simpler appender work? Does the appender expect the directory to exist?

Comment: thanks again.  Yes, I phrased my question incorrectly, no doubt... apologies.  As for System.out.println, I just tested this: in public static void main(), a first System.out.println message prints in the command prompt, but after I have set up the two logging handlers, a second System.out.println message fails to print!

Comment: I'm obviously going to have to start with a totally simple example, as you suggest.  And gradually add stuff... thanks for the suggestion... sigh.

Comment: @mikerodent it sounds like `System.out` has been redirected. This means you can't use it directly after this happens. At the start of your program you can do `static final PrintStream OUT = System.out;` to get the original even if it has been redirected.